# Searching for an image within another one

Tags: php, image, search

What I'm trying to achieve is an extension of browser automation testing (think selenium) where instead of searching for text in a webpage, I search for in image in a screenshot of the webpage.

There are many reasons this could be useful:

- detecting browser-specific UI defects
- avoiding complex checks to ensure page elements should look as expected (positioning, depth etc)
- a more user-oriented kind of test (users do not care about the website's code makeup, but how it looks)

To that end, the test would be looking for an image (aka fixture/sub-image) inside another image (screenshot/main-image). While the sub-image is expected to be a **part** of the screenshot, both images are expected to be of the same resolution, colour space and lossless (comparison).

This is for PHP, but I could integrate non-PHP solutions, so not a big problem.

Here's what I tried so far:

- translated [pixelmatch](https://github.com/mapbox/pixelmatch) into PHP (using pixel data export from native imagemagick php extension)

  - didn't work reliably
- custom brute-force check, also based on imagemagick pixel data export

  - quite slow
  - did not work reliably
- php/imagemagick [subImageMatch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.subimagematch.php)

  - extremely slow
  - couldn't properly interpret results - it gives me match positions even when match confidence is 0
- imagick cli `magick compare -subimage-search -metric AE -similarity-threshold 1.0 $MAIN_IMAGE $SUB_IMAGE null:`

  - works reliably
  - very slow (probably also because it paints a new image)
- visgrep

  - couldn't find distribution or an osx version
- rust/[find-subimage](https://docs.rs/find-subimage/latest/find_subimage/)

  - integrated this into PHP using `rust/ext-php-rs`, but..
  - a lot of false positives
  - quite slow (it tries to find multiple sub-images)
- customised rust/find-subimage

  - still a lot of false positives
  - still slow (even when running on SIMD)
- OpenCV - seems well suited to my task, but...

  - couldn't find a way to connect it to PHP

Next I'm considering trying OpenCV + `rust/find-image` + `rust/ext-php-rs` (I wanted to avoid this because it seems like a slipery slope to dependency hell).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Slightly off-the-wall suggestion.... if you find you can get the results you want with **OpenCV** you could throw the images (or just their names if they exist in your filesystem) into a **Redis** queue from PHP, then pop them out with some Python/C++ OpenCV to process them and return them via another queue. Just a thought if you are desperate.

Comment: You might look at [tag:vips] too which is blazing fast and has PHP bindings.

Comment: @MarkSetchell regarding the queue, it wouldn't fit the current flow, which is very linear and it would cause some large bottlenecks (send to queue, wait for it to be processed, pull back result, continue to next test).

Another option is to make a PHP library in C++ binding to OpenCV, but I'd rather avoid C++ if at all possible.

On the other hand, vips looks very promising, nice find!!

Comment: `magick compare -subimage-search ...` will run 10x-100x faster if you use -metric NCC on IM 7.

Comment: asked and answered on the libvips board here: https://github.com/libvips/libvips/discussions/3528

Answer (score 1):

In the end I went for libvips - it's incredibly fast and seems to work quite accurately.

After [installing the PHP bindings](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips#php-binding-for-libvips), I used the code below ([thanks to @jcupitt](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/discussions/3528)):

```php
use Jcupitt\Vips\Image;

function loadNormalizedImage(string $file): Image
{
    return Jcupitt\Vips\Image::newFromFile($file)
        ->colourspace('b-w')
        ->resize(0.0625);
}

function findImageInImage(Image $main, Image $sub): bool
{
    return $main->equal($sub)->min()
        || $main->fastcor($sub)->min();
}

echo "Loading screenshot.png ...\n";
$main = loadNormalizedImage('screenshot.png');

echo "Loading sample.png ...\n";
$sub = loadNormalizedImage('sample.png');

echo "Comparing...\n";
var_dump(findImageInImage($main, $sub));
```

Also thanks to @mark-setchell for pointing me to libvips.